# Ruby on Rails Form Submission Error and Success Messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm creating a landing page and I have two forms on my root page (trying to create a landing page). Very new to ruby on rails so forgive me because I'm going to explain this terribly.

The landing page controller (landing_controller) looks like this:

```
class LandingController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @email = Email.new
    @design = Design.new
  end
end
```

The emails_controller (emails_controller) looks like this:

```
class EmailsController < ApplicationController
protect_from_forgery with: :exception

def new
    @email = Email.new
end

def create
  @email = Email.new(params[email_params])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @email.save
      format.html  { redirect_to(root_path, :notice => 'Thank You For Subscribing!') }
      format.json  { render json: Email.create(email_params) }
    else
      format.html  { redirect_to(root_path)}
      format.json  { render :json => @email.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

    private

    def email_params
        params.require(:email).permit(:username, :email)
    end
end
```

and the designs controller (designs_controller) looks pretty much the same as emails_controller.

Then I have some validation in the email.rb model:

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :username, :presence => true
    validates :email, :presence => true
end
```

And again the design.rb looks pretty much the same.

The form I have on the landing page (root_path) index looks like this:

```
    <%= form_for @email, url: emails_path, html: {class: "email-form"} do |f| %>
    <% if @email.errors.any? %>
        <h3>Error</h3>
        <ul>
            <% @email.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
    <h2>Receive Notifications</h2>
    <%= f.text_field :username, :class => 'email-box', :placeholder => "First Name", :autocomplete => :off %>
    <%= f.text_field :email , :class => 'email-box', :placeholder => "Email", :autocomplete => :off %>
    <%= f.submit "Subscribe", :class => 'email-submit' %>
    <p class="info">- We'll update ​you ​when ​we launch our new website</p>
    <% end %>
```

When I submit the form breaking the validation I get no errors and if I submit the form following the validation rules I don't know if it creates a new entry in the database. If anyone can help I'd be very appreciative.

Comment: There's a disconnect between your controller and views. You aren't showing the "success" `:notice` anywhere and using `redirect_to` will discard your `@email` object on the page you've redirected to. I don't see you using `remote` anywhere on the form so the JSON parts aren't likely ever being used.

Comment: You should replace `@email = Email.new(params[email_params])` with `@email = Email.new(email_params)`.  `email_params` is a method which returns the permitted parameters from the form.  In terms of what is happening, you can look at the terminal where you are running the Rails server and you should see log messages.  You can also look at `log/development.log`.  Finally, you should get familiar with the Rails console where you can query the database and see what objects have been created/updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to render the landing controller index action rather than redirecting to it.  because on redirection, it does @email = Email.new and all the errors are gone for email. try this as create action in your emails controller

```
def create
  @email = Email.new(email_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @email.save
      format.html  { redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Thank You For Subscribing!' }
      format.json  { render json: Email.create(email_params) }
    else
      @design = Design.new
      format.html  { render "landing/index" }
      format.json  { render :json => @email.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

for success or errors messages, put this in your application.html.erb

```
<% if flash[:error].present? %>
  <p class='flash-error'><%= flash[:error] %></p>
<% end %>
<% if flash[:notice].present? %>
  <p class='flash-notice'><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: helpful links for success and error message: http://pupeno.com/2009/11/19/ensuring-the-displaying-of-flash-messages-in-ruby-on-rails/

Comment: never mind, there was just an out of place parenthesis. Thank you its working :)